# emacsのmewのレイアウトのカスタマイズ

Tags: emacs, elisp

emacsのメーラーmewで、サマリウィンドウ(メール一覧の表示)とメッセージウィンドウ（メール本文の表示）は、デフォルトでは上下分割で表示されますが、これを左右分割で表示したいです。
何卒ご教示お願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

自己レスです。
以下のコードでとりあえずやりたいことはできるようになりました。
今後細かいところでの不具合が出てきそうな気はしますが、これでcloseします。

```
(defadvice mew-window-configure (around my-mew activate)
  (flet (
         (split-window  (a b) nil)
         (delete-windows-on (&optional a) nil)
         )
    ad-do-it
))
```

Answer (score 1):

mew 自体には細工をしないで表示された上下分割のバッファを左右分割のバッファに変更するという事なら [emacs-rotate.el](https://github.com/daichirata/emacs-rotate) を使うと簡単にできそうですね